# How to diagnose why a latexmk invocation works on one system but not another (Linux vs. Windows)

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

I am trying to get a build script to run both on Linux and Windows. On Linux we're using TeXLive and on Windows MikTeX. In both cases `latexmk` is used to rerun `pdflatex` as often as needed to resolve the references.

Coming from the development of the script on Linux, it fails miserably on Windows after only one run (on Linux `latexmk` takes 3 runs of `pdflatex`) and I cannot figure out why.

On Linux, at the end of run 1, I get `mytexfile.aux` shown as a changed file. On Windows nothing like that happens. Consequently on Windows `latexmk` seems to see no need to rerun `pdflatex`.

Initially I thought this could be related to the fact that `latexmk` is a Perl script and perhaps curtails the precision of file timestamps. However ...

When running the `pdflatex` commands, which `latexmk` claims it executes (after cleaning, of course), *manually* the `.aux` file does indeed not change between run 1 and run 2 of `pdflatex`. The only two files that change are the `.fls` and `.log` files (`.aux`, `.fdb_latexmk`, `.out`, `.toc` remain unchanged). What's more, the `.toc` file is empty on Windows, which it isn't on Linux.

What I don't know as of yet is whether `latexmk` or `pdflatex` is the culprit here and whether the version differences between the individual packages in MikTeX and TeXLive respectively, play a relevant role in all this.

So how can I diagnose this issue further and more importantly how do I get this to run on Windows with MikTeX (I have no say in regards to why it has to be MikTeX on Windows and TeXLive on Linux)?

**Edit 1:** I basically grepped for `error` in the `.log` file after one comment on the question. The output was as follows:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
\GenericError  ...
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Digging further I can see that the character tripping up the LaTeX engine appears to be `é` ... no idea why it barfs on Windows, but not on Linux, though.

---

**On Windows (10 x64):**

Versions: `latexmk 4.63b`, `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7029 (1.40.20) (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)`

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -synctex=0 -interaction=batchmode  -recorder  "mytexfile.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
...
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 83 reference(s)
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

**On Linux (Ubuntu 16.04):**

Versions: `latexmk 4.41`, `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`

**NB:** ellipsis denotes that I removed some lines for brevity (but only those naming the references).

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 1 January 2015, version: 4.41.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -synctex=0 -interaction=batchmode  -recorder  "mytexfile.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'mytexfile.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
...
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 83 reference(s)
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'mytexfile.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -synctex=0 -interaction=batchmode  -recorder  "mytexfile.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'mytexfile.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
...
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 54 reference(s)
  Latex found 1 multiply defined reference(s)
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'mytexfile.aux'
      'mytexfile.out'
      'mytexfile.toc'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -synctex=0 -interaction=batchmode  -recorder  "mytexfile.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'mytexfile.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
...
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 54 reference(s)
  Latex found 1 multiply defined reference(s)
Latexmk: All targets (mytexfile.pdf) are up-to-date
```

Comment: The `latexmk` log for windows says `Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets`. What does the `pdflatex` log say?

Comment: I figured I'd check for updates, but on Windows I get this issue reproducibly even with the latest `pdflatex` version (`Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)`).

Comment: you're using Windows...that's your source of problem(s)...

Comment: @naphaneal well, unfortunately sometimes one doesn't have the choice, although I concur.

Comment: Windows works just fine, except when people start taking random advice from "experts" on the internet about how to improve it, and screw it up :)

Comment: @0xC0000022L could you please provide a MWE and the content of said script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had come to rely on `latexmk` showing me what went wrong with references so much, I didn't even think of looking into the `.log` file. Fortunately [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) set me straight in a comment.

From that I could see:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

\GenericError  ...
```

... followed by a few (mangled) lines seemingly showing the cause.

The problem is in the (Python-based) pre-processing step which differs between Windows and Linux, it seems. In the source code from which we extract bits and pieces for documentation I can see the following bytes: `c3 a9` which decode to `é` when treated as Unicode (see Python output):

```
>>> b"\xc3\xa9".decode('utf-8')
'é'
```

... but these get converted to `latin-1` (or probably that closely related standard Windows ANSI codepage depending on the locale), yielding an invalid byte sequence when treated as UTF-8 ... which in turn make `pdflatex` choke.

Comment: told ya, Windows is the source of problems...

Comment: It is not clear if it is the preprocessing step: you are using a rather new miktex with a new latex with utf8 preloaded, while your linux tex system is old and without utf8.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the opposite. The preprocessing step is a Python script. Roughly we extract documentation and type information from (C/C++) headers by way of Doxygen. That XML is then digested by a Python script which uses Jinja2 as templating engine to create LaTeX files. Now on Linux I know for sure the locale defaults to using UTF-8 and on Windows it doesn't. So the issue is that on Windows a file is produced with an invalid code (in terms of UTF-8), leading to pdfLaTeX barfing on it.

Comment: Did you try to copy the file created on linux to the windows system and compile it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yep, it works that way around. But not the other. The problems were 1. that Python defaults to a particular encoding (and a different one) on either platform and 2. that I didn't diligently check the log file for issues. On my end the mitigation is now to inspect the log file more thoroughly.